# How to show multiple string columns with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to show a simple chart using the google charts api.

I'm getting "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" as an exception.

I understand, according to the API docs, that Bar takes a String, Number, Number.

However how do I show data with the following structure? I'm used to thinking in Dimensions and Measures, crosstab etc.

```
Country|Code|Population
France |FR  |60000000
UK     |GBR |59000000
```

I'm using `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()`

Comment: What do you expect the graph to show with this data structure? What difference does the code column make?

Comment: I guess I should be able to see this extra metadata. I.e. Italy=IT. I managed to get the column showing by adding an annotation, but the chart was cluttered afterwards. Perhaps I could do a custom Tooltip displaying this extra info. I'm a little confused I guess but imagine I have another dimension called Product and not something like Code which is related to Country. :)